# Giving Same Number If Same Group

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I have dataframe like this
name status

```
+----+------+                      
|name|value |                                                  
+----+------+                                   
|  x |  down|                                             
|  y |normal|                               
|  z |  down|                                                
|  x |normal|                                  
|  y |  down|                       
+----+------+
```

If the names are same i want to put number 1,2,3 like this, new column must be like this

```
+----+------+------+   
|name|value |newCol|   
+----+------+------+   
|   x|down  |     1|   
|   y|normal|     2|   
|   z|down  |     3|   
|   x|normal|     1|    
|   y|down  |     2|   
+----+------+------+
```

```
win = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("name")
print("value")
dp_df_classification_agg_join = dp_df_classification_agg_join.withColumn("newCol",count("name").over(win))
```

Comment: ...okay. Do you have a question?

Comment: please provide your code and what you have done to achieve this

Comment: i edit my question

Answer (score 0):

First, replace the `count("name")` function with the `dense_rank()` function.

Then, replace this `win = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("name")` with `win = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("name")`